# POILogFactory, POILogger not found with an upgrade to poi 5.1.0

Tags: apache-poi

I just upgraded `poi`, `poi-scratchpad` and `poi-ooxml` to 5.1.0 and now the `POILogFactory` and `POILogger` classes are missing.

I have invalidated the intellij cache, reloaded maven projects, and rebuilt the project to no avail.

Comment: the logging has changed: https://poi.apache.org/components/logging.html